# Laravel 5 Connection could not be established with host kindmill.com [Connection timed out #110]

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp

I am trying to use smtp
this is my .env file configurations

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp

MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com

MAIL_PORT=587

MAIL_USERNAME=example@gmail.com

MAIL_PASSWORD=abcd

MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: I also got the same problem i fix it by changing the following lines in config/mail.php file.

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'kindmill.app123@gmail.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Your name here'),
    ],

Comment: i also do the same but its not work

Comment: Why gave the error "kindmill.com" not smtp.gmail.com ? Please help

Answer (score 1):

Had similar problem

Try restarting your server then,

`composer dumpautoload`

`php artisan config:clear`

And ensure you got have internet